# Extract the diagonal of data and regroup the numbers

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have the data as shown in below:

```
for a=1:2
    for b=1:3
        m{a,b}=zeros(3,3)
    end
 end

m{1,1}=[6 1 1;1 7 1;1 1 6];
m{1,2}=[3 2 2;2 5 2;2 2 6];
m{1,3}=[5 3 3;3 9 3;3 3 7];

m{2,1}=[2 4 4;4 5 4;4 4 8];
m{2,2}=[2 1 1;1 6 1;1 1 5];
m{2,3}=[6 2 2;2 7 2;2 2 8];
```

I would like to take the diagonal of each set of data only and regroup these numbers.For example,

```
%RESULT

row_1_1=[6;3;5]  %which 6 from m{1,1}(1,1), 3 from m{1,2}(1,1) and 5 from m{1,3}(1,1)

row_1_2=[7;5;9]  %which 7 from m{1,1}(2,2), 5 from m{1,2}(2,2) and 9 from m{1,3}(2,2)

row_1_3=[6;6;7]  %which 6 from m{1,1}(3,3), 6 from m{1,2}(3,3) and 7 from m{1,3}(3,3)

row_2_1=[2;2;6]  %which 2 from m{2,1}(1,1), 2 from m{2,2}(1,1) and 6 from m{2,3}(1,1)
```

and so on.

Any idea how to do get these result??Thanks~

Comment: Did you notice that column 1,:,1 equals diag(m{1,1}). Maybe you can make it easier if you reshape your problem.

Comment: Why do you want to store them as `row_1_1 ... row_2_3` instead of, say, `rows{1,1} ... rows{2,3}`?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
row_result = zeros(a,b,3);
for i=1:a
    for j=1:b
        for k = 1:3
            row_result(i,k,j) = m{i,k}(j,j);
        end
    end
end
```

For the sample data provided, this would yield results as follows:

```
>> row_result(1,:,1)

ans =

     6     3     5

>> row_result(1,:,2)

ans =

     7     5     9

>> row_result(1,:,3)

ans =

     6     6     7

>> row_result(2,:,1)

ans =

     2     2     6
```

Comment: can save the result like row_1_3=[6;6;7]??

Comment: You can of course: the simple approach would be to take off the two outer loops and hard-code each such variable; another approach (though I have not tried it out myself) is to create dynamic variable names as given [here](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/156268). The use of dynamic variable names however is not considered to be good programming practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're stuck with an ugly for loop to build your new matrix.

Is there some reason you're using a cell array for this, rather than some other data type, such as a higher dimensional matrix or array of structs? The point of a cell array is that the contents of each cell are entirely independent of each other, which means that you can't use ':' to access the internal fields of the cell contents.

Comment: In that case, just use a higher dimensional matrix: m=zeros(2,3,3,3); m(1,1,:,:)=[6 1 1;1 7 1;1 1 6]; etc....

Comment: and then, you'd have row_1_1=m(1,:,1,1)